# alamofire header + parameters

Tags: ios, swift, http-headers, alamofire

Hello World,

I come to you because, I try to send headers with parameters in the same function like this:

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.PUT, "url", headers: headers, parameters: parameters)
```

but maybe you already knew just headers are sent.

I tried also this way:

```
 let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
 manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
            "Authorization": token]

 manager.request(.PUT, "http://192.168.99.100:3030/users/\(identity)", parameters: parameters, encoding:.JSON)
```

but the headers are not sent..

What is the easy way to implement headers in alamofire?

Thanks by advance ;-)

regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set headers in dictionary just like other parameter and pass it in headers. for example

```
let Auth_header    = [ "Authorization" : token ]

Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.PUT, "url", headers: Auth_header, parameters: parameters)
```

You can check details [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

**HTTP Basic Authentication**

The authenticate method on a Request will automatically provide an NSURLCredential to an NSURLAuthenticationChallenge when appropriate:

```
let user = "user"
let password = "password"

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
     .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
     .responseJSON { response in
         debugPrint(response)
     }
```

Depending upon your server implementation, an Authorization header may also be appropriate:

```
 let user = "user"
 let password = "password"

 let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
 let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

 let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/password", headers: headers)
     .responseJSON { response in
         debugPrint(response)
     }
```

Comment: Thanks to give me the Way ;-)

Comment: with the api key , how to auth request sends a key and value in the header ?

Answer (score 0):

I already did what you said in the first comment but anyway there are just the headers sent:

```
let parameters : [String : NSString] = [
            "username": username,
            "email": email,
            "currentPassword": currentpassword,
            "newPassword": newpassword]        
let Auth_header    = [ "Authorization" : token ]

Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.PUT, "url", headers: Auth_header, parameters: parameters)
```

Resolved: The probleme was that I did't give the encoding in parameter

```
Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.request(.PUT, "url", headers: Auth_header, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

Thanks to EI Captain